# How to translate "я заболела тобой"?

Tags: перевод

Referring to the title of the [song by IOWA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os1dSz82SXU), what does it mean? I understood it literally as "I got sick with you" or "I made you sick", but I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Love is a sickness

Answer (score 3):

This might be not the best translation but it was my first association with the song you quoted: ["I'm mad about you"](https://youtu.be/MxtYzo0OLXs). Besides, it's just a nice song.

Answer (score 3):

"Я заболела тобой" is a Russian idiom which literally means: "I fell in love with you". Moreover the meaning is about female love: you can see the last "а" letter in word "заболела". If a man sang such words in any song it would be "заболел" (without last one "a").

Comment: Thank you. Can you show some other examples or sources to prove this is a common idiom?

Comment: Here is an amateur poem about love in Russian, where this speech turnover is used

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5d48241723371c00afdcbe1a/ia-bolen-stih-5e78ed6c8378cf16138d0846

Comment: As you can see its title is "Я болен" ("I'm sick"). And you can think of it is equal to "Я заболел" - I have some kind of illness. But then in the poem he speaks about love at all, so love is the very disease, roughly speaking - "Заболел тобой давно..." - I love you for a long time.

Comment: @I. Hasanov https://ru.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_(%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

It's idiom meaning fell in love (especially woman's love)

I think the roots of this idiom is in verses of Russian poetess [Marina Tsvetaeva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marina_Tsvetaeva)

Here's [the text (in Russian)](https://www.culture.ru/poems/36102/mne-nravitsya-chto-vy-bolny-ne-mnoi) written in 1915.

Verses become famous after a well-known movie [The Irony of Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irony_of_Fate) - here's [song from that movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJuCYR00IXw)